# boot project that exports tasks which themselves use third-party tasks

Tags: clojure, classpath, boot-clj

I'm modeling a collection of custom boot-clj tasks. The structure of the project is very similar to the one of [bootlaces](https://github.com/adzerk-oss/bootlaces).

The tasks defined in there work well when they refer to built-in tasks, which are required as `[boot.task.built-in :refer :all]`. One task however should make use of a third-party task from boot-cljs. Requiring it via `[adzerk.boot-cljs :refer [cljs]]` works well in the project's compilation and installation phase.

When requiring the tasks in another project, the following error occurs:

```
Could not locate adzerk/boot_cljs__init.class or adzerk/boot_cljs.clj on classpath.
```

**In other words:** What would one have to do if one of the exported tasks in [this file](https://github.com/adzerk-oss/bootlaces/blob/master/src/adzerk/bootlaces.clj) needs to use the `cljs` task.

Comment: Could you add an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: I just figured out, that it works when the cljs dependency is required inside the second project. I'll provide a MCVE afterwards..